# Introducing wait time in UNIX shell script for every 'n' executions

Tags: unix, ksh

I have 2 files: **file.dat** and **mapping.dat**.

**file.dat** contains entries (can contain duplicate), and **mapping.dat** is a static file which contains the entries and their corresponding session/job names separated by a comma.
I have developed a simple UNIX Shell script which runs in loop where for each entry in file.dat, it searches for the session/job name in mapping.dat and displays the output.

**Content of file.dat**

```
ekm
ckm
cnc
cnx
ekm
hnm
dam
```

**Content of mapping.dat**

```
#Entry,Job_Name#

ckm,BDSCKM
cnc,BDSCNC
cnx,BDSCNX
ekm,BDSEKM
azm,BDSAZM
bam,BDSBAM
cam,BDSCAM
oid,BDSOID
hnm,BDSHNM
dam,BDSDAM
```

**Current Script:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
for FILE in `cat file.dat`
do
        SESSION=`grep $FILE mapping.dat | cut -d, -f2`
        echo "For ${FILE}, Session launched is: ${SESSION} "
done
```

**Current output**

```
For ekm, Session launched is: BDSEKM 
For ckm, Session launched is: BDSCKM 
For cnc, Session launched is: BDSCNC 
For cnx, Session launched is: BDSCNX
For ekm, Session launched is: BDSEKM 
For hnm, Session launched is: BDSHNM 
For dam, Session launched is: BDSDAM
```

My question is I want to introduce a wait/sleep time for every 2 occurrences of output i.e. it should first display

```
For ekm, Session launched is: BDSEKM 
For ckm, Session launched is: BDSCKM
```

**wait for 90 seconds**, and then

```
For cnc, Session launched is: BDSCNC 
For cnx, Session launched is: BDSCNX
```

..and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try helping yourself using the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%`.

```
#!/bin/ksh
count=1
for file in $( cat file.dat )
do

  session=$( grep $file mapping.dat | cut -d, -f2 )
  echo "For ${file}, session launched is ${session}."

  if (( count % 2 == 0 ))
  then
    sleep 90
  fi
  (( count++ ))
done
```

Comment: You can simplify `count=$((count+1))` to `(( count++ ))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, I added in a message for unrecognised items (you can safely remove that by simply deleting  `|| session='UNRECOGNIZED'` from the first line of the while read loop). I'm not overly familiar with ksh, but I believe `read` is the same as bash in this context (I'm very familiar with bash).

I tested with your example data, and it works on both `ksh` and `bash`.

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Print 2 mappings every 90 seconds

FILE="./file.dat"
MAP="./mapping.dat"

while IFS= read -r line; do
        session=$(grep "$line" "$MAP") || session='UNRECOGNIZED'
        echo "For $line, session launched is: ${session#*,}"
        ((count++ % 2)) && sleep 90
done < "$FILE"
```

I used non greedy suffix removal (`#`) to isolate the 'session'.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe you can point out why `while ; do ... ; done` is a better pattern for reading from a file. Good luck to all.

Comment: Indeed, a while read loop is probably the safest way to process each line of a file, individually.
It can be a bit slower, mainly for larger files, as `read` does a system call for each byte (character) of text.
A `for` loop can work, and be faster, but relies on unquoted arguments, which is problematic. At least set `IFS=$'\n'` (bash for 'new line') then. In this case it's not so bad, as the data doesn't contain white space for example.

Answer (score 0):

To print the first 2 consecutive lines, then wait 90 seconds, then print the next 2 lines, etc.
Use the `%` modulo operator as suggested by Tony Stark. There is no need to initialize the counter.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $( cat file.dat )
do
  session=$( grep $file mapping.dat | cut -d, -f2 )
  echo "For ${file}, session launched is ${session}."
  (( count++ % 2 )) && sleep 90
done
```